# Unable to install flatpak on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, xfce, flatpak

[Trying to] Installing flatpak on Arch linux fails:

```
$ sudo pacman -S flatpak
resolving dependencies...
:: There are 3 providers available for xdg-desktop-portal-impl:
:: Repository extra
   1) xdg-desktop-portal-gtk  2) xdg-desktop-portal-kde
:: Repository community
   3) xdg-desktop-portal-wlr

Enter a number (default=1): 1
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (11) appstream-glib-0.7.18-1  gcab-1.4-1  geoclue-2.5.7-3  geocode-glib-3.26.2-1
              gnome-desktop-1:40.0-1  gnome-keyring-1:40.0-1  libstemmer-0+713-2  ostree-2021.1-1
              xdg-desktop-portal-1.8.0-1  xdg-desktop-portal-gtk-1.8.0-1  flatpak-1.10.2-1

Total Download Size:    0.63 MiB
Total Installed Size:  29.29 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'ostree-2021.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.rackspace.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'ostree-2021.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.evowise.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'ostree-2021.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.rackspace.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'ostree-2021.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.rackspace.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (failed to retrieve some files)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

What's the correct way to download and install flatpack on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it is not advisable to install an individual package after `-Sy` or `-Syy`. If you need to update your mirrors with `-y` to install a package, you should combine it with a full system upgrade `-u`:

```sh
sudo pacman -Syu flatpak
```

You might not see immediate breakage with `-Sy <package>`, but eventually something will break with continued use. If `<package>` happens to pull in new lib versions, then any program that depends on those libs [will break since they will still be built against the old libs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with running `sudo pacman -Syy` first

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes happen. you can solve it using `pacman -Syu flatpak`.
If it didn't solve then you have to change your repository server either from `/etc/pacman` or `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`.

Answer (score 0):

Update the system with
`pacman -Syu` and try again

buy I highly recommend going with AUR packages